SPFx Application Customizer Footer: Show Only When Scrolled to Bottom
I'm developing a SharePoint Framework (SPFx) extension that adds a custom footer to SharePoint pages. While I've successfully implemented the footer using the bottom placeholder, it's currently visible at all times. I want to modify the behavior so the footer only appears when the user scrolls to the bottom of the page.
    import { BaseApplicationCustomizer, PlaceholderContent, PlaceholderName } from '@microsoft/sp-application-base';
import { Footer } from './Component/Footer';
import { SPFI } from "@pnp/sp";
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDom from 'react-dom';

export default class HelloWorldApplicationCustomizer extends BaseApplicationCustomizer<IHelloWorldApplicationCustomizerProperties> {
  private _sp: SPFI;
  private _bottomPlaceholder: PlaceholderContent | undefined;

  public onInit(): Promise<void> {
    this.context.placeholderProvider.changedEvent.add(this, this.renderPlaceHolders);
    return Promise.resolve();
  }

  private renderPlaceHolders(): void {
    const linksListName: string = this.properties.linksListName || 'FooterLinks';
    const feedbackListName: string = this.properties.feedbackListName || 'Feedback';

    this._sp = getSP(this.context);
    if (!this._bottomPlaceholder) {
      this._bottomPlaceholder = this.context.placeholderProvider.tryCreateContent(
        PlaceholderName.Bottom
      );

      if (this._bottomPlaceholder && this._bottomPlaceholder.domElement) {
        const element: React.ReactElement<{}> = React.createElement(
          Footer,
          {
            sp: this._sp,
            linksListName: linksListName,
            feedbackListName: feedbackListName
          }
        );
        ReactDom.render(element, this._bottomPlaceholder.domElement);
      }
    }
  }
}

Expected Behavior
Footer should be hidden by default
Footer should appear only when user scrolls to/near the bottom of the page
Footer should hide again when scrolling back up
Transitions should be smooth
What I've Tried
I've attempted to use the bottom placeholder provided by SPFx, but I'm unable to control its visibility based on scroll position. I'm not sure about:
The best way to handle scroll events in an SPFx extension
How to properly manage the footer's visibility
How to implement smooth transitions
Question
How can I modify my SPFx extension to make the footer appear only when scrolling to the bottom of the page? I need a solution that:
Works with React components
Handles scroll events properly
Manages component lifecycle correctly
Implements smooth transitions
Environment
SharePoint Framework version: [your version]
React version: [your version]
Browser: Chrome/Edge/Firefox
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
